# Problems upgrading APC 3.0.19 -> 3.1.4

Tags: linux, apc, gentoo

On the gentoo Linux server I use, I've just upgraded APC from 3.0.19 to 3.1.4 and it appears as if something is not working properly there. It appears as if cache entries which should have been deleted (either explicitly or via TTL expiry) stay in place and so cache use keeps growing until it reaches the max usage memory and then the server becomes extremely slow.

Anyone with some experience on this upgrade?

Thanks

Here's my apc.ini

```
extension=apc.so
apc.enabled="1"
apc.shm_segments="1"
apc.shm_size="1536"
apc.num_files_hint="2500"
apc.ttl="7200"
apc.user_ttl="86400"
apc.gc_ttl="3600"
apc.cache_by_default="1"
;apc.filters=""
;apc.mmap_file_mask="/tmp/apcphp5.XXXXXX"
apc.slam_defense="0"
apc.file_update_protection="2"
apc.enable_cli="1"
apc.max_file_size="5M"
apc.stat="0"
apc.write_lock="1"
apc.report_autofilter="0"
apc.include_once_override="0"
apc.rfc1867="0"
apc.rfc1867_prefix="upload_"
apc.rfc1867_name="APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS"
apc.rfc1867_freq="0"
apc.localcache="0"
apc.localcache.size="512"
apc.coredump_unmap="0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was seemingly a Gentoo linux related bug. I've reported it on http://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=343485 and it's been fixed for APC 3.1.5

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with APC 3.1.5 when I set the apc.shm_size with only the numeric value.
Try out `apc.shm_size="1536M"`, maybe it helps (the default value in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php) also uses this formula)

Comment: I've added the M as well and it made no difference. Please see my own answer. Thanks.