# Fatal error: Call to undefined function apc_store()

Tags: php, apc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [apc_store isn’t working between requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152526/apc-store-isnt-working-between-requests)

Can anyone tell me why can't I run this function [apc_store()] in my host?

In phpinfo I can see the apc module installed....

Thanks for any help.

---------------- adding Details -----------------

PhpInfo()=>

```
Configure Command    './configure' '--disable-fileinfo' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-zend-multibyte' '--enable-zip' '--prefix=/usr' '--with-bz2' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-curlwrappers' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-gettext' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libexpat-dir=/usr' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/' '--with-mm=/opt/mm/' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-pgsql=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-pspell' '--with-sqlite=shared' '--with-tidy=/opt/tidy/' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'
```

Server API  CGI/FastCGI

```
APC Support enabled
Version 3.1.9
APC Debugging   Disabled
MMAP Support    Enabled
MMAP File Mask  no value
Locking type    pthread mutex Locks
Serialization Support   php
Revision    $Revision: 308812 $
Build Date  Oct 9 2012 21:12:08

Directive   Local Value Master Value
apc.cache_by_default    On  On
apc.canonicalize    On  On
apc.coredump_unmap  Off Off
apc.enable_cli  Off Off
apc.enabled On  On
apc.file_md5    Off Off
apc.file_update_protection  2   2
apc.filters no value    no value
apc.gc_ttl  3600    3600
apc.include_once_override   Off Off
apc.lazy_classes    Off Off
apc.lazy_functions  Off Off
apc.max_file_size   2M  2M
apc.mmap_file_mask  no value    no value
apc.num_files_hint  1000    1000
apc.preload_path    no value    no value
apc.report_autofilter   Off Off
apc.rfc1867 Off Off
apc.rfc1867_freq    0   0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_ upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600    3600
apc.serializer  default default
apc.shm_segments    1   1
apc.shm_size    32M 32M
apc.slam_defense    On  On
apc.stat    On  On
apc.stat_ctime  Off Off
apc.ttl 0   0
apc.use_request_time    On  On
apc.user_entries_hint   4096    4096
apc.user_ttl    0   0
apc.write_lock  On  On
```

Please let me know where I am doing wrong...

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a little more detail.  Can you provide a copy of the output from phpinfo?

Comment: `apc_store()` is available from apc 3.x. What is your apc version?

Comment: I added more details. Please help me! 
@Rohit Kumar Choudhary -> That doesn't solve my problem.... :(

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with the people here.... My question is completely different from the reference. Their apc_store function was not working the way it should.... but for me it's not working at all.... Moreover I posted the phpinfo... I don't see anything wrong there as far as the reference question is considered